# GeoNodes delete geometry not working properly?

Tags: node-editor, geometry-nodes

When the object I'm trying to delete makes contact with the target (I detect it using the ray cast node `isHit`) some times it doesn't delete it.
[image]

I have also tried using a geometry proximity node to detect the hit; the problem persists. I also tried using various targets very close to each other.
[image]

I have the understanding that this is a common problem, however I couldn't find a solution.

Sorry for not providing the file.

[image]

Comment: Without the Blender file to give it a try, and only a limited view of your GN graph, it is difficult to give advice... I notice that you have a "Join Geometry" node without a following "Merge by Distance" node. Could it be that for duplicated points, some are not deleted ? Could you provide your Blender file using https://blend-exchange.com with a setup producing the undesired behaviour ?

Comment: sorry Helios, but i can only downvote your question. You didn't even give us your whole node tree and not even a part which is useful. How shall we know what your named attribute is? how is it filled? Do you also call a car service shop and ask for help without providing your car and just saying "it makes noises"? So pls provide blend file, so we can check it out on our own.

Comment: Please rearrange your node tree before screenshoting. The problem was off screen and not provided in the screenshot. Also use descriptive file names like "geo-node-particle-collision".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were doing the following things.

1. Check for collision using a vector "*velocity*".
2. Delete based on the collision.
3. Modify the vector "*velocity*".
4. Move by "*velocity*".

Hence your particles could easily move through objects.

You needn't change the vector between collision detection and movement.
The solution:

1. Check for collision using a vector "*velocity*".
2. Delete based on the collision.
3. Move by "*velocity*".
4. Modify the vector "*velocity*".

[image: node tree]